# In DocuSign API createReceipient method parameter description

Tags: docusignapi

For createReceipient method currentRoutingOrde, errorDetails, recipientCount are mentioned as the request parameter? If that is so ,Could you please explain about the parameters?

Comment: Please provide links to the resources you are referring to

Comment: In update EnvelopReceipient method: [1].https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/?categories=Envelopes&tags=EnvelopeRecipients&operations=update [2].https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/update/